# Apache Spark: In PairFlatMapFunction, how to add tuples back to the Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>> return type

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

I'm new to spark. I have been working on a code involving two datasets. Hence I started with a PairFlatMapFunction in which i'm doing the processing of a mapper.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> trainingArray = trainingData.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, Integer, String>(){
        public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(String s) {
//code to form the tuples of type Tuple2<Integer, String>
// new Tuples2<Integer, String> 
}
```

How to add the tuples back to the iterable class to be processed by a reducer (reduceByKey).

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks!!

I have found the answer for this question.

We need to define the below ArrayList

```
List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> result = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, String>>();
```

Add the tuples as below

```
result.add(new Tuple2<Integer, String>(keyValue, concat));
```

And return the result.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better alternative if your result only consists of one tuple.

```
return Collections.singletonList(new Tuple2<Integer, String>(keyValue, concat)).iterator();
```